# simple question from set theory/measure theory

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

This is a simple question.

On pages 5-6 of Measure Theory,Vol 1, Vladimir Bogachev he writes that:

for $E=(A\cap S)\cup (B\cap (X-S))$

Now, he writes that:

$X-E = ((X-A)\cap S) \cup ((X-B)\cap (X-S))$

But I don't get this expression, I get another term of $((X-B)\cap (X-A))$

i.e, $X-E =( ((X-A)\cap S) \cup ((X-B)\cap (X-S)))\cup ((X-B)\cap (X-A))$.

I believe I did it correctly according to De-Morgan rules and distribution.

I am puzzled...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}
x\notin E&\iff x\notin (A\cap S)\text{ and }x\notin (B\cap (X-S))\\[0.05in]
&\iff (x\notin A\text{ or }x\notin S) \text{ and }(x\notin B\text{ or }x\notin (X-S))\\[0.05in]
&\iff(x\in (X-A)\text{ or }x\in(X-S)) \text{ and }(x\in (X-B)\text{ or }x\in S)
\end{align*}$$
If $x\in S$, then we must have $x\in (X-A)$ because, in this case,
$$(x\in (X-A)\text{ or }x\in(X-S)) \iff x\in (X-A).$$
Similarly, if $x\in X-S$, we must have $x\in (X-B)$ because
$$(x\in (X-B)\text{ or }x\in S)\iff x\in(X-B).$$

Comment: Ah, OK. Yes, S is a subeset that is disjoint to A and B. I am an idiot... :-D

Comment: Happens to all of us sometimes :) Glad I could help.